# Python Dictionary output issues

Tags: python, dictionary, mergeddictionaries

I am new to python and this forum. Online learning isn't working for me so I can't just go to a tutor. It could be something minor I am forgetting. I welcome any assistance you can give me.

I am trying to make the output look like this: Her name is Emmylou; She is on track to graduate in Fall 2021; Her bill is paid; Her major is Archeology; She belongs to these school clubs–Photography, Acting and Glee

```
Emm = {'name' : 'Emmylou', 'graduate' : 'Fall 2021', 'bill' : 'paid', 'major' : 'Archeology', 'clubs-' : 'Photography, Acting and Glee'}

for Key, Value in Emm.items():

print(f"Her {Key} is {Value} and she is on track to {Key} in {Value}; Her {Key} is {Value}; Her {Key} is {Value}; She belongs to these school {Key} {Value}")
```

The output is a mess and looks like this when I run it:

```
Her name is Emmylou and she is on track to name in Emmylou; Her name is Emmylou; Her name is Emmylou; She belongs to these school name Emmylou
Her graduate is Fall 2021 and she is on track to graduate in Fall 2021; Her graduate is Fall 2021; Her graduate is Fall 2021; She belongs to these school graduate Fall 2021
Her bill is paid and she is on track to bill in paid; Her bill is paid; Her bill is paid; She belongs to these school bill paid
Her major is Archeology and she is on track to major in Archeology; Her major is Archeology; Her major is Archeology; She belongs to these school major Archeology
Her clubs- is Photography, Acting and Glee and she is on track to clubs- in Photography, Acting and Glee; Her clubs- is Photography, Acting and Glee; Her clubs- is Photography, Acting and Glee; She belongs to these school clubs- Photography, Acting and Glee
```

Comment: Since you know which key should be placed in sentence, instead of iterating over dictionary you can just do Emm['key'] to fetch value. Ex: print(f"Her name is Emm['name'] and she is on track to graduate in Emm['graduate'];....

Comment: The dictionary does not conceptually have an order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ass other people tell you, you are iterating over the dictionary and in each iteration the  key and value are replaced and printed in a new line.

If  you want to print in a single line using the dictionary, you can try to convert the dictioray  in an array and printed using the format method.

```
Emm = {
    'name' : 'Emmylou',
    'graduate' : 'Fall 2021',
    'bill' : 'paid',
    'major' : 'Archeology',
    'clubs-' : 'Photography, Acting and Glee'
}

items = []
for (key, value) in Emm.items():
    items = items + [key, value]
print("Her {} is {} and she is on track to {} in {}; Her {} is {}; Her {} is {}; She belongs to these school {} {}".format(*items))
```

Comment: The only issue here is that with many versions of Python the order in which dictionary keys are iterated on is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

In your codes, you are iterate over each key-value pair in your data; so you ended up printed 5 times, each time with a key-values pair, instead of printing 1 times, with all key-value pair.

Try this.

```
Emm = [
    ('name', 'Emmylou'),
    ('graduate', 'Fall 2021'),
    ('bill', 'paid'),
    ('major', 'Archeology'),
    ('clubs-', 'Photography, Acting and Glee'),
]

flat_items = [item for pair in Emm for item in pair]
print("Her {} is {} and she is on track to {} in {}; Her {} is {}; Her {} is {}; She belongs to these school {} {}".format(*flat_items))
```

Comment: The only issue here is that with many versions of Python the order in which dictionary keys are iterated on is not guaranteed.

Comment: Oh, I have been using the new versions for too long that I forget about this. Looks like OrderDict might be overkill, updated using list of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm going to assume that you have actually indented the print statement in your code because otherwise it wouldn't work at all.

The problem is that for every loop you're filling in the same key/value pair in all places.

Depending on the purpose you could get the statement by doing something like;

```
Emm = {'name' : 'Emmylou', 'graduate' : 'Fall 2021', 'bill' : 'paid', 'major' : 'Archeology', 'clubs-' : 'Photography, Acting and Glee'}
print(f"Her name is {Emm['name']} and she is on track to graduate in {Emm['graduate']}; Her major is {Emm['major']}; Her clubs - is {Emm['clubs-']}")
```

The other problem you could face with iterating through the dictionary is that unless you are using python 3.7 or above there is no guarantee of the order in which items will be saved in a dictionary. Therefore your key/value pairs may not come out in the same order they went in.

Comment: The code  you have provided as a solution will run into an error due to case sensitivity in variables, in the print statement 'emm' is used but the e in emm needs to be capitalized, second the print statement will be printed 5 times since that is the length of the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks @BrendaMejia, I've edited the code accordingly